# Sort Object Javascript by Number

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

```
var object = [
    { name: 'Mar', age: 32 ,height:40},
    { name: 'Carla', age: 10 ,height:15},
    { name: 'Hazel', age: 5 ,height:80}
];
```

Is it possible to sort based on the **age** element and generate a new sorted object?

**Expected result:**

```
var newobject = [
    { name: 'Hazel', age: 5 ,height:80},
    { name: 'Carla', age: 10 ,height:15},
    { name: 'Mar', age: 32 ,height:40}
];
```

Or you could also return the result sorted in an array, instead of returning it in an object... whatever... uncomplicated, but return it sorted .

```
var new_sorted_array = [
   [Hazel, 5 ,80] , 
   [Carla, 10 ,15], 
   [Mar, 32 ,40]
];
```

Comment: `object.sort(({age: a}, {age: b}) => a - b)`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, you can try below two options

1. Using array sort method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
2. Second option is by looping array and using Object.values to get output in the format specified in question

```js
var object = [
    { name: 'Mar', age: 32 ,height:40},
    { name: 'Carla', age: 10 ,height:15},
    { name: 'Hazel', age: 5 ,height:80}
];

//Sort array by property age
console.log("Sort by age", object.sort((a, b) => a.age -  b.age))

//Using object values
console.log("Sort by age -option2", object.map(v => Object.values(v)).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]))
```